# CAT NMEA WITH GREP IN FILE

Tags: gps, raspberry-pi3, nmea

I wish to get le last position of GPS Beacon (NMEA) on my RPI 3+
i use the code below to put data in file

```
grep --line-buffered -h '$GNGGA' /dev/ttyACM0 > gps.txt
```

But i wish to save only the last line, to manipulate after this one like this

```
$GNGGA,094354.00,5034.68284,N,00303.38074,E,2,12,0.77,46.5,M,45.9,M,,0000*78
```

final result each 5 sec

```
{"time": "09:43:54","lat": "50.3468284", "lon": "03.0338074", "alt_m": "45.9", "alt_ft" : "150.59"}
```

The questions are :

- how i can get only the last line of grep in my file ?
- which kind of script is better for manipulate the result (python, bash, cron) ?

Comment: nmea is easy to parse, no need to grep

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a good thing
i use PYNMEA2 ... is a good python script to read all NMEA
I hope to post soon the result of my projet :)